# Access concatenating multiple text columns into one Text Control. Failing

Tags: textbox, ms-access-2010, concatenation

According to MS the following is possible

```
myTextBox.Control Source = [Firstname] & " " & [LastName]
Control Source set to this '=[FirstName] & " " & [LastName]'
```

My testing shows this is correct in a small test DB.

However in my production DB this is failing.  Both fields are Short/Text so I'm not sure what is going on here.

I get #Type! displayed instead.

Also these variations produce these results:

```
[LastName]  ! This works
=[LastName]  ! This works
=" " & [LastName]  ! This works
[FirstName] ! This works
=" " & [FirstName] ! This Doesn't work, displays #Type!
=[FirstName] ! This Doesn't work, displays #Error
```

So something is strange with my FirstName field!

Any ideas what I should check or look at!

Comment: Is it possible that at least one entry in your table is `NULL` for this column?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be the naming of the TextBox control.

It was called FirstName.  When I changed it to FullName it behaved as expected.

However I'm not sure why the name made any difference!

Maybe there was some underlying connection between the textbox and the field when the names coincide???

Comment: Never a good idea to name a control the same as any part of the Control Source. If you look at the tests that worked and those that failed, you will see anytime you used 'FirstName' as a combination with anything else, it fails.